# Routing in a faulty hypercube

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Suppose I colored a fraction (say $e$) of the edges of the $n$-dimensional hypercube. (the set $\{0,1\}^n$, with edges between points which differ by a single coordinate)

Let $c<0$ be some constant, such that at least $1-\frac e3$ of the vertices are between $\left||x|-\frac n2\right| < c \sqrt n$.

That would mean, that in the middle layers ($\frac n2 - c \sqrt n \le |x| \le \frac n2 + c \sqrt n$) at least $\frac{2e}3$ of the edges are colored.

If I pick u.a.r. a monotonic path from level $\frac n2 - c\sqrt n$ to level $\frac n2 + c\sqrt n$, could I argue that with some constant probability at least $\frac e3$ of the edges in that path are colored?